# How to get hold of the existing code base/projects in squeaksource.com?

Tags: smalltalk

I am very new to smalltalk. And I am currently trying to wrap my head around GNU smalltalk (pharo environment). Upon browsing through the introductory session of pharo by example, I came to know that there is a lot of code base in the squeaksource repository submitted by the programmers. The pharo site very well says that anyone can refer this huge code base available.

I would like to know how I can actually browse, load and peek into the source code of the projects within my IDE so that I can get a basic understanding about smalltalk syntax and how to code in pharo? Please help me with this.

Comment: FYI: GNU Smalltalk is a very different environmetn from Pharo. You're just using Pharo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Monticello Browser which is in the menu. Check the section 6.3 Monticello in PharoByExample.

In addition, there is a draft of a Monticello chapter for the future book Pharo By Example Vol. 2: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/27018/Monticello.pdf